# It shows black screen when trying to load Map on device with ionic 2 Google Map Native plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

[image: screenshot of the error]

**Note** This project must be run on a device, iOS or Andriod

**Background:**

I had installed the native google maps plugin into my ionic 2 project using the command 
`$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"`
as shown in the following link: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/

Then i'd run the command `$ ionic platform add ios`
and then `$ ionic build ios`

Everything goes as expected till this point.
When i try to display a map, i see a black screen, don't know whats missing!

**Code:**

/src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

/src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import {
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapsLatLng,
  CameraPosition,
  GoogleMapsMarkerOptions,
  GoogleMapsMarker
  // GoogleMapsMapTypeId
} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

      let map = new MapPage();
      map.loadMap();
    });
  }
}

class MapPage {
  constructor() {}

// Load map only after view is initialize
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {
    // make sure to create following structure in your view.html file
    // and add a height (for example 100%) to it, else the map won't be visible
    // <ion-content>
    //  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
    // </ion-content>

    // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
    let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

    let map = new GoogleMap(element);

    // create LatLng object
    let ionic: GoogleMapsLatLng = new GoogleMapsLatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);

    // create CameraPosition
    let position: CameraPosition = {
      target: ionic,
      zoom: 18,
      tilt: 30
    };

    // listen to MAP_READY event
    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {
      // move the map's camera to position
      map.moveCamera(position); // works on iOS and Android
    });


    // create new marker
    let markerOptions: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
      position: ionic,
      title: 'Ionic'
    };

    map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
          marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
  }
}
```

/src/pages/home/home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Could someone please help in figuring out the problem. Your help is deeply appreciated.

[Link to documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/)

[Link to project repo](https://github.com/prateekanilkedia/ionicGoogleMaps)

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let map = new MapPage();
  map.loadMap();`
```

MapPage is a plain typescript class. It is not a component and it wont run lifecycle hooks like this:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }
```

Also the call `map.loadMap()` in `App.html` is not working because your element is in `home component`.

I suggest you move map related code to **home component**.
Also use [viewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child) to get the `map div` which would be an [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html) object.

## Home Component

```
  constructor() {}
@ViewChild('map')
  private mapElement: ElementRef;

// Load map only after view is initialize
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

  loadMap() {

    let map = new GoogleMap(this.mapElement.nativeElement);

   //...etc etc
  }
}
```

Angular Documentation Reference: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/

Answer (score 0):

In app.scss, add:

```
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor{
   background: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Loading map on iOS platform was not working. It was showing black screen. However the map request was updating correctly on Google console.

Solution: I had to add the following code in .scss file -

```
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor{
    display: none !important;
}
```

This worked and loaded map correctly.

Comment: HI, I've tried your solution and black screen has dissappeared but the map is not loaded, the MAP READY event is fired and markers are showed but the map background and the animations not showing. What would be doing wrong? Same code on android works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution was, do not initialize the map on the constructor, initialize it on the ionViewDidLoad.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Maps');
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.loadMap();
    }, 1000)

  }
```